# How to get sqlite file from database folder to verify encryption in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqlcipher

I'm using SQLCipher to encrypt my DB and I would like to get the **.sqlite** file to open it in a DB Client and just verify that the data is encrypted.

The problem is that I can't get the file within `/data/data/<app.name>/databases`. I'm using the Android Emulator.

I've been trying to pull the file:
`adb pull /data/data/<app.name>/databases/databaseName.sqlite`
but I get: **adb: error: remote object '/data/data/`<app.name>`/databases/databaseName.sqlite' does not exist**.

So I deiced to get into the Emulator with `adb shell` and list the folders and files to verify the DB name, but I get **permission denied**. I searched how to solve this and found `adb root` but I get: **adbd cannot run as root in production builds**.

I've been searching for this, but I didn't get something useful.

So first at all, I would like to get the **.sqlite** file, secondly I would like to know why I'm getting the: **adbd cannot run as root in production builds**.

P.S. I append an image of what I'm getting from the console.
[adb root command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw6fs.png)

Comment: An option could be to use the Genymotion emulator which allows access to app data. Another alternative is to copy the file from within the App to a location. I use both methods, (the latter as part of the App to allow backup/restore) to copy databases directly into SQlite Manager.

Answer (score 0):

To get the path of your database(s) simply use `context.getDatabasePath(<databaseName>)`.
If you can't use adb to pull the database using the path, try backing up the app  by using `adb backup` command which doesn't require root.